# Why am I getting an ERROR while using WITH statement in psql cli?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm trying to create a new user to user and database using postgresql.

```
sudo su postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE USER $db_user WITH PASSWORD '$db_pass'\""
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "with"
LINE 1: CREATE USER  with PASSWORD ''

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, [`CREATE USER` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html) does not use `WITH` keyword when assigning password.

```
sudo su postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE USER $db_user PASSWORD '$db_pass'\""
```

Or you can use [`createuser` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html) to create the user.